# Why is the potential difference on a wire equal to zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential, voltage

I was studying Electromagnetic topics and there's something that I don't understand. If we have a cell connected to an ideal circuit (like the figure)

[image]

The textbooks say that the $\Delta V_{ab}=0$, and I understand that despite the voltage is zero it is able to establish current. But why $\Delta V_{ab}$ is zero? I mean

$\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \Delta V_{ab}=-\int_A^B \vec{E}\cdot \text
{d}\vec{r} \neq 0
\end{equation*}$

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the circuit is talking about steady-state.  Prior to steady-state, there is a field between A and B.  This field is sufficient to establish a current.  But once established, no field is required to maintain the current in an ideal wire.

In a real wire, there will be a minimal field sufficient to maintain the current against the minimal resistance.

You have draw the electric field that would surround a charge dipole in a vacuum.  But the wire is not a vacuum.  It has mobile charges that rearrange themselves in response to the field.  This rearrangement excludes (or nearly excludes) the electric field between A and B.  Therefore your equation holds.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in electric circuits, there is surface charge accumulation along the wire that maintains an electric field along the wire so that charge can move through it, so $V_{AB}\ne 0$.

But in electric circuits (as is probably the case here) when we also  assume the wire to be a perfect conductor,  we can consider the points A and B to have the same voltage so that the points A and B have no potential difference. In other words, in that case $V_{AB}=0$.

Comment: But why "we can consider the points A and B to have the same voltage"?